# Comparing similarities of two curves

Tags: r, algorithm

I have two curves that I would like to compare. One curve is a reference curve, and the second one is collected and fed into the R script to be compared with the second curve. (The black curve is the reference, the purple one is the sample.)
[image]

I would like my script to spit out a percent similarity between the two curves, but I'm not sure where to go from here. I've looked into cross correlation and Frechet distance, but they seem difficult to implement and I'm not sure if I understand the math behind them.

Another confounding factor is that the two curves are created experimentally, but they aren't ordered by time (i.e. the ordering of the vectors governing these curves doesn't go from bottom left to top right). Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Suppose the two curves were of exactly the same "shape" but were offset from each other by some constant.  Would you want to report them to as having 100% similarity?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks for a statistical method and belongs at Cross Validated.

Comment: As an extension of @zkurtz' comment, please explain how the similarity should be quantified.

Comment: If they were exactly the same shape but were offset, that could be 100% similarity. I already have a few lines of code that allow the user to shift the curve themselves by selecting alignment points between the two curves. @Roland, sorry this is my first post, I don't know what Cross Validated means, I just posted here looking for help.

Comment: @ErBen www.crossvalidated.com, a sister site for statistics. Don't worry, this question has been flagged and will probably be migrated there.